How to avoid duplicate words within an array
How to avoid duplicate words within an array. In the following scenario
First scenario: I want all 3 players to be present in the output including Phil. Phil is a subset of Phillies so it should not be removd from the output.
Second scenario: But I want "New York Mets", "Philadelphia Phillies" to be present in the output but Phillies should be removed since it matches a word in Philadelphia Phillies
Third scenario: I want Cristiano Ronaldo alone to be present in the output, since Cristiano is already present as part of the bigger word it should be removed.
# Initial array
football_players = ["New York Mets", "Philadelphia Phillies", "Phil"]
# football_players = ["New York Mets", "Philadelphia Phillies", "Phillies"]
# football_players = ["Cristiano", "Cristiano Ronaldo"]

# Function to remove smaller words contained in larger words
def remove_subwords(players):
    result = []
    
    for player in players:
        # Check if the player name is a substring of any other name in the list
        if not any(player in other and player != other for other in players):
            result.append(player)
    
    return result

# Call the function and print the result
filtered_players = remove_subwords(football_players)
print(filtered_players)


What's the logical explanation for what to remove, except this one very specific example?

Its in the title, duplicate words. Wasnt that clear? Its not a specific example, just giving samples on where it is failing

There is no exact duplicate here, and you're being fairly vague about your example too. You just want to remove "Phillies" from "Philadelphia Phillies"? Or you want to remove the "Philadelphia Phillies" entry in its entirety?

@user352290: Why should "Phillies" be removed but not "Philadelphia"?  Where in your code do you make any attempt to modify a string?  When encountering a "duplicate", if your goal is to remove the existing "duplicate" from the result and then add the new one, where in your code do you attempt to do that?  "I want" is not really a technical problem.  What specific logic are you trying to implement, and what prevents you from implementing it?

If you want shorter names to remain, but longer names which contain those shorter names to be omitted, then first sort your list by string length; then iterate over it much in the way you do, and only append players to result if none of the strings already in result occur in player…?

@David "Phillies" should be removed since it's part of "Philadelphia Phillies" since its part of a bigger word. but "Phil" shoud not be removed since it doesn't match a word in whole. I want this logic to be dynamic across all words. I want the longer names to remain. The above code doesn't handle "Phil" properly as it gets removed.

You want to remove "Phillies" from "Philadelphia Phillies"?! How in the magic AI do you want to do that? What's the rule? "Phillies" isn't a substring of "Philadelphia" or anything else.

@user352290: ""Phillies" should be removed since it's part of "Philadelphia Phillies" since its part of a bigger word." - And why shouldn't "Philadelphia" be removed?  It'a also part of "Philadelphia Phillies" and is a bigger word.  It sounds like you're not necessarily stuck on the technical implementation of your logic, but on defining what logic you want to implement in the first place.  Please take some time to edit the question and clarify specifically what isn't working as expected in the code shown.

And currently "Phil" gets removed, because you're checking whether player exists within any other player before appending it to result. And, yeah, "Phil" exists in "Philadelphia Phillies", so it gets omitted. But this code doesn't appear to be anywhere near what you're trying to do anyway, so not much point in trying to fix it.

I want the word Phil to match in whole with the bigger word and not as a subset of Phillies. I don't want the contains logic here but more of a word matching.
Philadelphia need not be removed since there is no match with other words in the array.

Yeah, nah, you're not really clarifying anything. If "Phillies" should be removed because "Phil" is contained in "Phillies", then why shouldn't "Philadelphia" be removed as well? Or if that's not what you want, then I still don't understand what you want. This would be a lot easier if you edited your question to clearly present your input, your desired output, and a logical explanation of why input should turn into output.

You're almost there. If we take Philadelphia Phillies, Phillies, Phil as the test cases we'll see that using in doesn't quite get the desired result.
>>> 'Phillies' in 'Philadelphia Phillies'
True # yes
>>> 'Phil' in 'Philadelphia Phillies'
True # no

What we need instead is to compare whole words against whole words rather than contains. We can do this using str.split
>>> 'Philadelphia Phillies'.split()
['Philadelphia', 'Phillies']
>>> 'Phillies'.split()
['Phillies']
>>> 'Phil'.split()
['Phil']

From there you can adapt your any check to see if any word in the list is contained in the other list.
Finally you can use len to get the string length and decide which string to keep.
